# How to decrease display:block in size

Tags: html

Newbie programming.

I'm creating a signature, but the block in the background is sticking out on the left and right side. How can I make it smaller?

```html
<td>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/TEST" color="#252e42" class="sc-hzDkRC kpsoyz" style="display: block; background-color: #252e42;">
    <img src="assets/twitter-icon-2x.png" alt="twitter" color="#252e42" height="24" class="sc-bRBYWo ccSRck" style="max-width: 135px; display: block; background-color: #252e42;">
  </a>
</td>
<td width="5">
  <div></div>
</td>
```

Comment: @Pete this user is using an HTML [email signature construction system](https://gist.github.com/MaxMcKinney/eb4127058d2e68176f639e85d9126d40)

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the max-width to less than 135px I do it for 90px.
Also make the display to `inline-block` to remove the block display from a tag

```html
<a href="https://twitter.com/TEST" color="#252e42"
   class="sc-hzDkRC kpsoyz"
   style="background-color: #252e42;"><img
    src="assets/twitter-icon-2x.png"
    alt="twitter" color="#252e42" height="24"
    class="sc-bRBYWo ccSRck"
    style="max-width: 90px; display: inline-block; background-color: #252e42;"></a>
```

Comment: It is also useful for people not to give simply code only answers but to also explain what you changed and why it works; as people can and do often miss this in code. Thanks. And welcome to Stack OverGnome `:-D`